# Having trouble with has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I finally figured out a way to let a user save favorites through a joined model.  Here's my user model:

```
has_many :pictures, :through => :favorites
```

If I want to get the pictures the user favorited, I can call

```
@pictures = user.pictures
```

Originally, this would show all the user's uploads and not favorites, but I still want to be able to show all their uploads.  I would like to be able to call @user.pictures for all uploads and @user.favorite_pictures for their favorited.  I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
has_many :pictures
has_many :favorites
has_many :pictures, :through => :favorites, :as => :favorite_pictures

### @user.favorite_pictures produces an error
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error lies in your 3rd line,

```
has_many :pictures, :through => :favorites, :as => :favorite_pictures
```

You already defined `:pictures` and the `:as` option is only used for polymorphic associations. Try this instead:

```
has_many :favorite_pictures, :through => :favorites, :source => :picture
```